# Add keyboard shortcut + mouse click event to every page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am looking for simple solution of my problem.
Pressing ctrl+alt+lmb should fire my script and I can achieve that using content_scripts, but content_scripts does not have access to chrome.*.

Any suggestions?

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "name" : "Incognito Shortcut",
    "content_scripts" : [
        {
           "matches"    : ["*://*/*"],
           "js"         : ["core.js"],
           "run_at"     : "document_end",
           "all_frames" : true
        }
    ],
    "permissions" : [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

core.js

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if(e.altKey && e.ctrlKey) {
        // do stuff
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard approach in such situation, is that you'll have to pass messages from content script to the background page (which has access to the most of chrome api's). E.g. content script will send message to the background-page and background page will call some appropriate chrome api

If you will read articles [Content-Scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) and [Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) from official documentation, you should be able to implement it easily.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had to miss 'Message Passing' page.